# How to include a condition inside a string in ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I want to place a variable within a string, but also have a condition on the variable

something like:

```
x = "best"

"This is the #{if !y.nil? y else x} question"
```

outside the string I can do `y||x`. what do I do inside the string?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
"This is the #{y.nil? ? x : y} question"
```

or

```
"This is the #{y ? y : x} question"
```

or

```
"This is the #{y || x} question"
```

you can use `y||x` inside interpolation just like outside it

Answer (score 4):

You can absolutely do the same within a string

```
y = nil
x = "best"

s = "This is the #{y || x} question"
s # => "This is the best question"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the ternary operator:

`"This is the #{!y.nil? ? y : x} question"`